# Vue-Router Should I use return when using next() in beforeEach?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am currently using the following code as a hook in each of my routes:

```
router.beforeEach(async(to, from, next) => {
  /**
   *
   * @type {boolean}
   */
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth) {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      next('/login');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else if (isAuthenticated()) {
    next('/home');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

My question as the title indicates is if I should use `return` after calling the `next()` method .. something like this:

```
...
if (requiresAuth) {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      next('/login');
      return; <--- should I use return here?
    } else {
      next();
      return; <--- should I use return here?
    }
}
```

I am confused on whether it is necessary to use it or not .. could you clarify my doubt please ..

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) for the global before each guard. There is no need to return, your code is wrapped in `if - else` and will only call `next()` once as described on the Vue Router docs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to return, as you have an if/else and no code after that.

But someone could argue that early bail-out improves readability. So having this code:

```
if (requiresAuth) {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      next('/login');
      return;
    }

    next();
}
```

Can be seen as more readable than the alternative.

Another reason for returning is future proofing. If you know for a fact that you want to return this will raise a warning (if using a linter) if someone adds code in the future

```
if (requiresAuth) {
    if (!isAuthenticated()) {
      next('/login');
      return;
    } else {
      next();
      return;
    }

    // adding code here will trigger an unreachable code warning.
}
```

So even if the 2 ways are equivalent, `returning` from the function does bring some benefits.